# Payment Information block in view order

Tags: orders, adminhtml, blocks

for orders paid by credit card I have the name of the payment that appears in the block 'payment information' but orders with a custom-paying mode I just have this `'Order Placed WAS using EUR'`

I don't find how add this information.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the **`$this->setTemplate()`** method in your custom module

```
class <company>_<Name>_Block_Info extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    /**
     * Payment rendered specific information
     *
     * @var Varien_Object
     */
    protected $_paymentSpecificInformation = null;
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('payment/info/default.phtml');
    }
}
```

Then goto

> /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/{payment/info/default.phtml

Comment: My class extend to Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract.
is it possible to add information in this class?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see the template location is to :

- Enable Admin Template Path Hints (since different payment method uses different folder naming structure in there block folder)

See

- [Enable template path hint in admin pages - Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373481/enable-template-path-hint-in-admin-pages-magento)

Method 1

```
 INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
   VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');
```

Method 2

Create a custom module with config.xml

```
<config>    
    ...    
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <dev>
                <debug>
                    <template_hints>1</template_hints>
                    <template_hints_blocks>1</template_hints_blocks>
                </debug>
            </dev>
        </admin>
    </stores>    
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have custom payment you need create block class  in which you have showing payment info

You need to got payment Model page where  you need to define block  which showing  the data

Suppose that at location `app/code/local/CompanyName/NewModule/Model/` `PaymentMethod.php` is

Payment model class here you need to `define Payment information block class` add

`protected $_infoBlockType = 'youBlockType/payment_info';` code

**Step2:** Define payment Block  information class

```
   <?php class CompanyName_NewModule_Block_Payment_Info extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
    {


        protected function _construct()
        {
            parent::_construct();
            $this->setTemplate('custompayment/mypayment.phtml');
        }
```

**Step3:** `mypayment.phtml` create at `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/custompayment`

And code in this file  is

```
  <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethod()->getTitle()) ?>
    <?php if($this->getInfo()->getAdditionalData()): ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

`$this->getMethod()` give payment method object content   if it give then you can  get Creadit  card

Comment: yes i tested.This function return the good payement but in the block the name doesn't show."Order Placed WAS using EUR" appear only.

Comment: hi i ahave change class extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info from Mage_Core_Block_Template

Comment: this funtion $this->getPaymentHtml() return void instead of my custom payement.this method is use in Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info